# Drawing a 2D silhouette of an island in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to draw a 2D silhouette of an island/land of sort in C++ with OpenGL. It is just a simple island that looks something like the one [here](http://d-junzo.deviantart.com/art/Blue-Island-81332165?q=boost%3apopular%20vector%20island&qo=20)

I tried ways like drawing polygons, fill the colour black and then hard-code tons of vertex points to get the shape of the island and also to keep the edges look rough like the one in the example. But I feel that this really isn't the best way to do this because the number of vertices is just too many. It is also very difficult to tweak because it's not like I'm in Photoshop where I could just pull/add/change the points visually.

Are there any better and more clever way to draw a 2D island silhouette to get the mountain-like edges? As for the overall shape of the island, is my naive way to plant tons of points to form the polygon shape the only way?

I have just started on OpenGL and will be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: why not just use a single textured quad with an alpha channel/mask?

Comment: hmm..pardon if I sound too newbie. Since the silhouette is entirely in a solid black colour, why would I need textures? How can I use quad and alpha channel mask to draw the island out? I still need to hard code the list of vertices, or I don't have to?

Comment: I think "awoodland" means: Draw a plane (2 triangles), texture it with an image representing the island silhouette, and activate the alpha to get transparency around the island silhouette. Place the plane at the background and that's it. This way you can edit it in photoshop and display it with OpenGL.

Comment: So looks like there is no easy way to draw it directly in the code itself and plotting the points is the only way?

Comment: You can directly draw with `glWritePixels`, but it's really not a good way of doing it. Textures are stored on the graphics card, but `glWritePixels` copies data from host CPU to GPU every frame.

Comment: @xEnOn: You should no hardcode your geometry anyway.

Comment: @awoodland Do you mean `glDrawPixels`, or is `glWritePixels` some new GL3/4 function I have not yet heard about?

Comment: @datenwolf: yea, I'm trying to avoid this. But looks like there is no way I could avoid if I needed the geometry to be created out of just the code itself.

Comment: @awoodland: I couldn't find `glWritePixels` in the OpenGL sdk docs. This function would still require me to plot out all the vertices, right?

Comment: @awoodland: I would try your suggestion to use alpha channel mask if I still couldn't find an easy to do this. Do you have any places that you can point me to get started with alpha channel masking? I have never tried alpha channel mask in OpenGL before. Also, wouldn't masking almost like just importing an image into the scene? I mean since it is just a black island, why do I still mask it when simply importing a png file would give a same effect as masking?

Comment: An alpha mask is very similar to importing an image, but it gives you a way to create high resolution images without needlessly using 10000 verticies. @christian - You're right I meant `glDrawPixels` - goes to show how often I've used it!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this here are two simple ones;

Easy way: As said in the comments, create the island in an image editor (with alpha) and draw as a quad/tris with blending enabled.

Harder way: Import a vector graphic (vector meaning points making a shape) and draw as polygons. This could get complicated for a newbie if using an existing format. Also, not as efficient as method 1, but can have a much nicer visual effect especially if you plan on zooming/scaling.

In the end it is entirely up to you how you want to implement it, but the first method is straight-forward and easy, I recommend that for a newbie (be sure to come back to it later and try method 2 though ;) ).